# I am getting java heap space error while inserting a record to the database?

Tags: java, oracle, heap-memory

I am getting a java heap space error but while trying to insert a record to the database. I am not sure how come oracle is able to consume the heap and why it is consuming this much. The error is occuring on this line:

```
 Connection con       = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs         = null;
    String sqlString     = null;
    DaoUtility dUtil     = DaoUtility.getInstance();

    try
    {
      con = dUtil.getConnection();
      . . .
      dUtil.executeUpdate(ps);
```

Here is the log:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>           at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:52)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.BufferCache.get(BufferCache.java:226)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getCharBuffer(PhysicalConnection.java:7643)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setupBindBuffers(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2949)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2355)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3571)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:172)

Comment: can you post some more code

Comment: You are passing a PreparedStatement which is `null`. I would expect an error in this case, but it should rather be a `NullPointerException`, `IllegalArgumentException` or something like that.

Comment: @Philipp Note the ellipsis above the call. Anyway, this question is not much about the detailed Java code that OP is using.

Comment: Check whether you have closed i.e., con.close() has been done or not.
Repeated calls to the method(I assume the code posted is in a method) could create problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle JDBC driver is notorious for memory consumption. Please read about the [configuration parameters](http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2012/07/managing-oracle-jdbc-memory-usage.html) available to you to control its memory consumption. Especially take note of `oracle.jdbc.maxCachedBufferSize` for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this error is thrown when there is insufficient space to allocate an object in the Java heap. In this case, The garbage collector cannot make space available to accommodate a new object, and the heap cannot be expanded further. Also, this error may be thrown when there is insufficient native memory to support the loading of a Java class. In a rare instance, a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError may be thrown when an excessive amount of time is being spent doing garbage collection and little memory is being freed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also check the JDK version for JDBC and your application. Sometime mismatch between two also lead to such error.

Also you can just give a try to insert the record in to some another (simple)table. This is to confirm is the issue is with inserting into specific table (due to more no of rows or volume of data).